# Difference between regex "(\d)(?=\d)\1" and "(\d)(?=\d\1)"?

Tags: python, regex

I came across the backreference concept in regex and was experimenting with those. However I could not understand the difference between these 2 regex. Suppose I have data string as `5152249435`

`"(\d)(?=\d)\1"` matches 515**22**49435 but `"(\d)(?=\d\1)"` matches with **5**1522**4**9435.

A digit followed by another digit then followed by the 1st capturing group. Isn't both mean the same thing. Or what am I missing?

Comment: `(?=` is a forward lookahead it does not actually consume a character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(\d)(?=\d)\1` reads, "match a digit and save the one-character string to capture group 1, provided the next character is also a digit (required by the positive lookahead `(?=\d)`) then match the next character if it equals the content of capture group 1".

Positive lookaheads (and other "lookarounds") are assertions that must be satisfied but do not affect the match that is returned.

It's clear this regular expression can be simplied to `(\d)\1`.

This regex simply matches two digits in a row if they are the same digit.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qDKEIV/1)

---

`(\d)(?=\d\1)` reads, "match a digit and save the one-character string to capture group 1, provided the next two characters are any digit followed by the digit saved to capture group 1 (required by the *positive lookahead* `(?=\d\1)`).

If there is a match it is the single digit saved to capture group 1.
[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Sg0bnl/1)

Answer (score 0):

It's all about the lookahead which requires a forward match but does not advance the current location in the string.

The first regex matches repeating digits

```
(\d)        find a digit
(?=\d)      that is followed by a digit (positive lookahead)
\1          immediately followed by the original match
```

It's the same as `r"(\d)\1"`. The lookahead isn't needed because the group match is already a digit.

The second regex matches a digit that is repeated 2 characters ahead

```
(\d)        find a digit
(?=\d\1)    that is followed by any digit and then the original match
```

It matches the first `5` in `515` because has the same digit twice with a single digit in between. The same with `494`.

This second match only advanced one digit. Had you tested 51512249435, you would have gotten an extra match **5****1**5122**4**9435.

Answer (score -1):

In the first pattern, it's any digit.
In the second pattern, it must be the same digit as the one captured in the first capturing group.